# Delete a named value

Tags: r, vector, subset

I have a vector with named values like this:

```
> dput(v)
structure(c("in", "in", "out"), .Names = c("A", "B", "C"))

> v
    A     B     C 
 "in"  "in" "out"
```

I want to remove the value for a name like `"B"`. I tried things like `v["B"] <- NULL`, `v[-"B"]`, and `v[!"B"]`, but none brought me closer to a solution.
I feel there must be a trivial solution, but I just cannot find it (Chapter 6 of the introduction could benefit from adding an example).

Comment: Note: I wanted to add a "remove" or "delete" tag, but such generic concept tags don't exist (yet), and I may not define new tags yet. So maybe the description for a "remove" tag would be: "Remove an item from a container".

Comment: Such a tag is not necessary. Your question has a title and nobody is going to search within [tag:remove] or follow it.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `names` and `!=`

```
v1 <- v[names(v)!="B"]
v1
#   A     C 
# "in" "out"
```

Comment: So it would be `v <- v[names(v) != "B"]`?

Comment: @U.Windl  If you are updating the same object, yes